# Можно ли в php узнать, что вызываемый метод класса является последним в цепочке вызовов?

Tags: php

Пример:

```
class Example {
    public turnLeft(){
        //поворот налево
    }
    public turnRight(){
        //поворот направо
    }
}
$a = new Example();
$a->turnLeft()->turnLeft()->turnRight();
```

Можно ли внутри методов turnLeft() и turnRight() определить являются ли они последними в цепочке вызовов? В данном примере последним является turnRight(). Если, к примеру, метод последний, то необходимо выполнить `echo 'last method';`

Answer (score 1):

Нет, такой возможности не существует. Это всего лишь удобный синтаксис, который базируется на том, что в каждом методе вы возвращаете объект и у него вызываете метод.

Comment: Это вопрос скорее на интерес. Т.е., понятно как отрабатывает цепочка, и что в итоге нужно добавить завершающий метод, наподобии ->end(); Но, вероятно, есть возможность узнать последний вызываемый метод прямо из самого метода, может кто-нибудь уже изворачивался.

Answer (score 1):

Зато можно воспользоваться [магическими методами](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php) и получить это:

```
<?php
class Example {
    protected $foo;

    public function turnLeft()
    {
        //поворот налево

        $this->foo = 'left';
        return $this;
    }

    public function turnRight()
    {
        //поворот направо

        $this->foo = 'right';
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->foo . "\n";
    }
}
$a = new Example();
echo $a->turnLeft()->turnLeft()->turnRight();
echo $a->turnLeft()->turnLeft()->turnRight()->turnLeft();
```

Результат

```
right
left
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/668c4038911409442c343db4565ed809b9d3c31e